# Get Billing Addresses in dropdown in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get the dropdown list for billing addresses in Magento, I can see the following block of code for shipping, but essentially want the billing or am I doing something wrong?

```
$this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('shipping');
```

I have tried changing this to 'billing' with no joy

Comment: where you want to get the billing address dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get billing address as dropdown by this code

```
echo Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing::getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing');
```

Refer `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.php`