# Magento: can't retrieve saved billing address

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem trying to show an already saved billing address in the checkout process.
Basically, the existing code (OnePageCheckout) uses the following code to show a dropdown list with existing addresses:

```
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?> // For billing
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('shipping') ?> // For shipping
```

The problem is that the billing dropdown has the same values as the shipping one.

The code that shows the dropdown is the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>  // for billing
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('shipping') ?> // for shipping
```

Shipping is correct, Billing shows the Shipping values.

But if I perform the following query on the DB:

```
select *  from sales_flat_quote_address where customer_id = <my_customer_id>;
```

I can clearly see the 2 addresses, one with `address_type` shipping, one with `address_type` billing.

The method reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757287/get-billing-addresses-in-dropdown-in-magento) has the same problem.

I'm stucked...any hints is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

MySQL SELECT:

```
SELECT address_id, same_as_billing, address_type FROM sales_flat_quote_address WHERE customer_id = 9419;

+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| address_id | same_as_billing | address_type |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
|      28338 |               0 | shipping     |
|      28353 |               0 | billing      |
|      28354 |               0 | shipping     |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento saves customer's address(shipping and billing only) as in `sales_flat_quote_address` as a sales-quote attribute not like a customer attribute. So we can keep two different  address. And of course you can see two different address billing and shipping. But there is field in that table called `same_as_billing`. Check this out. This filed contains `0` or `1`. Magento will display same address for shipping and billing if it contains `1` or else it will display two different address (actually there is option during check out like same as shipping address).  I think I have solved your problem.

**Update:**

It is not a necessary that a customer should have a default address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just checked on the table, please check my updated question (to format the query's output).

Comment: It seems like that customer didn't put any order yet and he didn't saved his (any) address as a default one. Which means he don't have default address. So it will return null.